# Modify custom request headers AWS Amplify

Tags: aws-amplify

I want to modify custom request headers for `page-data.json` in Gatsby react framework. Specifically I want to set custom request header of `cache-control` to `cache-control: public, max-age=0, must-revalidate`. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

To set custom headers

1. Sign in to the AWS Management Console and open the Amplify Console.
2. In the navigation pane, choose the app to set custom headers for.
3. Choose App settings > Custom headers.
4. In Custom header specification, choose Edit and add below code and click Save.

   ```
    customHeaders:
      - pattern: 'page-data.json'
        headers:
        - key: 'cache-control'
          value: 'public, max-age=0, must-revalidate'
   ```